# Override a value in my @RestContoller dynamically. Webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

So, I'm creating a authentication service with Java20 and WebFlux, I've this `@Secured` annotation to validate my Bearer token and add in the parameter `ClientDto` the token Owner.
I`m using` WebFilter`to intercept the request and validate my token, but I don't know how to override my`ClientDto` value.

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/v1/client")
@RestController("ClientControllerV1")
@Secured
public class ClientController {

    @PostMapping
    public Mono<ClientDto> createClient(@RequestBody CreateClientRequest createClient, ClientDto tokenUser){
        return clientServiceImp.createClient(createClient.getRole(), createClient.getUsername(), createClient.getPassword(), createClient.getEmail(), createClient.getTags());
    }
```

I tried get RequestMappingHandlerMapping and find a way to change the value but I didn`t find a way.

Comment: You don't as that isn't there yet. That is only there after the conversion. Instead of rolling your own security framework I suggest Spring Security which does this and much more and you can use standard mechanisms to get the object.